# sending json object using $.ajax doesnt get to servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

I'm trying to send json Object whit Ajax(POST) to my Servlet,
the Ajax seem not to be send to the servlet, means that the doPost function dosent Run.
And after the Ajax been send how do i get the data from it and just print to console.
thanks.

**index.jsp**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
    pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Welcome please fill in the details, and then click Submit</h2>
<hr/>

<input value="Submit2" type="submit" onclick="submitform()">
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform() {
      alert('sending json');

      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/MyServlet',
            data: JSON.stringify({name:"hod"}),
            success: function(msg){
                alert('wow' + msg);
            }
        });

      alert('done json');

    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>WebApp-01</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.srk.pkg.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**MyServlet.java:**

```
package com.srk.pkg;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
/*
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public MyServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("doGet");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("doPost");
    // get the object and print to console
    }

}
```

Comment: Your browser has a console that logs javascript execution and HTTP requests. Check it for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you need to do is use jquery or javascript to get your form data into a javascript object. If your data is a single form element e.g. First name then use var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value() to get the value from the form element.

If your form data is multiple form elements then collect your data and store it in a javascript object in the form of an array or so.

Your HTML page is not enclosed with a `<form>` tag so the DOM does not push your data in your submit hence no data is sent to your ajax call.

In your ajax call you should set the Content-type header to accept Json object. I see you are stringifying your object which is good.

Your javascript object will then be posted to the server once there you will need a Json to java mapper to create the object mapping. If you are using struts then there exist a Json to java mapper. Other solutions to mapping would be GSON or Jackson.

Your server function should return an object /string whatever you want to return. That data would be accessible in your success callback function in the variable msg as you have it there. If your return an object e.g. Student you can print console.log(msg.firstname) or print a returned string.

I hope this helps you and it's a guide as to the approach and what you need to research and implement.